# How to recursively sum parent child hierarchy value in jquery table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have parent child hierarchy data loaded from database into html table structure where i need to enter value in some of leaf node.

When I enter value in any leaf node then recursively do sum in hierarchy up to last parent node.

I need to do this using jquery/javascript and html table tree format.

This is my html

```js
//This is textbox change event.

$(document).on('change', '.item-balance', function () {
    if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val())) return false;
    calculatehierarchybalance($(this).closest('tr'));
});

//Below is calculation function. Here problem is that it only sum up to single level instead of all the parent of leaf node.  

var calculatehierarchybalance = function (currentrow) {
    var inpctrl = $(currentrow).find(".item-balance");
    var _total = 0;

    $.each(currentrow, function () {
        var ss = $('tr[data-id=' + $(currentrow).attr('data-parentid') + ']');
        //console.log($(ss).attr('data-id'), $(ss).attr('data-parentid'));

        if (inpctrl.is('input:text')) {
            _total = _total + Number(inpctrl.val());
        }
        else {
            _total = _total + Number($(ss).find('td.td-bal').text().trim());
        }
        
        $(ss).find('td[data-readonly=true]').text(_total);
        if ($.isNumeric($(ss).attr('data-parentid')))
            calculatehierarchybalance($(ss));
    });
};
```

```css
.table {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
         
         .table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
        border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e7eaec;
        line-height: 1.42857;
        padding: 8px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
           .table-Balance td {
                border: 1px solid #eee;
            }

            .collapse-tr .toggle {
                background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-minus-empty-128.png");
            }

            .expand-tr .toggle {
                background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-plus-empty-128.png");
            }

            .toggle {
                height: 9px;
                width: 9px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .panel-title {
                color: #fff !important;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-balance" id="tblbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Cat&#225;logo de Cuentas</th>
                <th class="text-right">Balance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse-tr level0" data-id="81" data-parentid="" data-readonly="true"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="1" data-accountid="2">
                        <td style="padding-left:0px;" class="align-middle"><span class="toggle collapse-tr"></span>1-Activos</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="true">
    0.00                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="1" class=" level1" data-id="82" data-parentid="81" data-readonly="true"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="1" data-accountid="3">
                        <td style="padding-left:12px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.1-Activos Corrientes</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="true">
    0.00                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="2" class=" level2" data-id="83" data-parentid="82" data-readonly="true"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="4">
                        <td style="padding-left:18px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.1.10-Efectivo y Equivalentes</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="true">
    0.00                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="3" class=" level3" data-id="84" data-parentid="83" data-readonly="true"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="5">
                        <td style="padding-left:24px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.1.10.1-Cajas</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="true">
    0.00                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="4" class=" level4" data-id="85" data-parentid="84" data-readonly="false"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="6">
                        <td style="padding-left:30px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.1.10.1.10-Caja General</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="false">
    <input class="form-control text-right input-sm inputdecimal item-balance" id="Balance" name="Balance" placeholder="Ingresar saldo" type="text" value="0.00" />                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr data-depth="3" class=" level3" data-id="87" data-parentid="83" data-readonly="true"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="8">
                        <td style="padding-left:24px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.1.10.2-Bancos</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="true">
    0.00                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="4" class=" level4" data-id="88" data-parentid="87" data-readonly="false"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="9">
                        <td style="padding-left:30px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.1.10.2.10-Banco #1 (Cambiar Nombre)</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal" data-readonly="false">
    <input class="form-control text-right input-sm inputdecimal item-balance" id="Balance" name="Balance" placeholder="Ingresar saldo" type="text" value="0.00" />                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="4" class=" level4" data-id="86" data-parentid="84" data-readonly="false"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="7">
                        <td style="padding-left:12px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.2-Dep&#243;sitos sin aplicar</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal">0.00
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-depth="4" class=" level4" data-id="86" data-parentid="84" data-readonly="false"
                        data-baseaccounttype="1" data-accounttype="2" data-accountid="7">
                        <td style="padding-left:18px;" class="align-middle"><span class=" "></span>1.2.1-Dep&#243;sitos sin aplicar 1</td>
                        <td class="text-right td-bal">
    <input class="form-control text-right input-sm inputdecimal item-balance" id="Balance" name="Balance" placeholder="Ingresar saldo" type="text" value="0.00" />                    </td>
                    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Expected Output as below image when I entered value in leaf node that will reflect to all related parent node.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: And what did you try? Where is the exact problem? I see no JS. Take it step by step and research how to, its all here on SO already.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for an answer, but I enjoyed giving an answer :)

I chose a bit different approach:

- create an object that holds the data recursively
- make the value "reactive" by using `getter`s

I guess neither too efficient nor very scalable, but solves the problem in a logically simple way.

```js
// sum the value of immediate children's values
function getRecursiveVal(items) {
  return items.length ? items.reduce((a, c) => a + c.val, 0) : 0
}

// recursive object getter
// gets an item by label
function findByLabel(label, item) {
  if (item.label === label) {
    return item
  } else if (item?.length || item?.items?.length) {
    let ret
    for (let i = 0; i < item.items.length; i++) {
      ret = findByLabel(label, item.items[i])
      if (ret) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return ret
  }
}

// array to hold the data
// if readonly is false, then the item's
// beginning val is 0
// if readonly is true, the the items's
// beginning val is the sum of its items vals
const arr = [
  {
    label: "1-Activos",
    get val() { return getRecursiveVal(this.items) },
    readonly: true,
    items: [
      {
        label: "1.1-Activos Corrientes",
        get val() { return getRecursiveVal(this.items) },
        readonly: true,
        items: [
          {
            label: "1.1.10-Efectivo y Equivalentes",
            get val() { return getRecursiveVal(this.items) },
            readonly: true,
            items: [
              {
                label: "1.1.10.1-Cajas",
                get val() { return getRecursiveVal(this.items) },
                readonly: true,
                items: [
                  {
                    label: "1.1.10.1.10-Caja General",
                    val: 0,
                    readonly: false,
                    items: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                label: "1.1.10.2-Bancos",
                get val() { return getRecursiveVal(this.items) },
                readonly: true,
                items: [
                  {
                    label: "1.1.10.2.10-Banco #1 (Cambiar Nombre)",
                    val: 0,
                    readonly: false,
                    items: [],
                  },
                ],
              }
            ],
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: "1.2-Depósitos sin aplicar",
        get val() { return getRecursiveVal(this.items) },
        readonly: true,
        items: [
          {
            label: "1.2.1-Depósitos sin aplicar 1",
            val: 0,
            readonly: false,
            items: [],
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
];

// row template
function rowHtml(data) {
  let html = '<tr>'
  html += `<td>${ data.label }</td>`
  if (data.readonly) {
    html += `<td>${ data.val }</td>`
  } else {
    html += `
      <td>
        <input
          data-inputfor="${ data.label }"
          value="${ Number(data.val) }"
        />
      </td>
    `
  }
  html += '</tr>'
  return html
}

// flattening the object for
// HTML table
function recTableHtml(item) {
  let html = rowHtml(item)
  if (item?.items?.length) {
    html += item.items.map(e => recTableHtml(e)).join("")
  }
  return html
}

const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");

function updateTable(container, arr, fn) {
  container.innerHTML = arr.map(e => fn(e)).join("")
}

// first paint of the table
(function(container) {
  updateTable(tbody, arr, recTableHtml)
})(tbody);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // general action on input
  $("body").on("input", "input", function(e) {
    const thisLabel = this.getAttribute("data-inputfor")
    const item = findByLabel(thisLabel, arr[0])
    item.val = Number($(this).val())
  
    updateTable(tbody, arr, recTableHtml)

    // setting focus to last char of input
    // so there's continuous typing 
    var value = $(`[data-inputfor="${thisLabel}"]`).val();
    $(`[data-inputfor="${thisLabel}"]`).focus().val('').val(value)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```